# A brush cup, or a brushing cup?

Tags: grammar

What should I call the cup while brushing my teeth: a brush cup or brushing cup?

Some people might say "a cup you use for brushing", but I am looking for an adjective form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard it as ***a rinsing cup***. It's the cup you use for rinsing your mouth while brushing your teeth.

Answer (score 2):

You can say *toothbrush cup* or *toothbrushing/tooth-brushing cup*, though not everyone uses one, [especially in the West](http://eastversusmidwest.blogspot.com/2009/09/teeth-brushing-in-china.html). In the West, where most people (per the article)  normally just let the water run while brushing & rinse their mouth without using a cup, a *toothbrush cup* is mainly for storing one's toothbrush between uses.

Comment: I am regularly admonished to cease the cited wasteful practice by my environmentally astute college-age offspring, to their credit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no adjective + noun pair, nor single noun in English which we use to mean "the cup used when brushing one's teeth." Since we commonly brush our teeth in the bathroom, though, if you were to say **the bathroom cup**, most NAmE speakers would understand you.

Comment: This is what I see it called in ads and such, or sometimes bathroom *tumbler* (presumably because that is the specific kind of cup most often seen in bathrooms). See, for example, http://www.target.com/c/bathroom-accessories-bath-home/-/N-5xtvb%7Cd_item_type_all%3ABathroom%20Tumbler?Sort=Featured&clearCategId=5xtvb&Nao=0 This is probably a specifically American usage, since I don't think "bathroom" is standard everywhere for the place where you brush your teeth.

Comment: @1006a I can't remember the last time I heard the word _tumbler_ (in reference to drinkware) in non-advertizing speech. Ref. "bathroom," you're probably right.